# Unexpected blocking behavior on OSX, Pthreads and calls to system(3)

Tags: macos, pthreads, posix, system-calls

I am working on a program to start a long running process (afplay, with long sound files) using system() and at a later time possibly decide to terminate this process.  It seems that it would be straightforward to invoke a system("prog") call and then later a system("killall prog") call.  Using pthreads, I fire up a thread to invoke the initial  system("prog") call and then later if application detects that its time to terminate early, the main thread will call system("killall prog").  Through print statements I can see that the main thread properly detects the logic to stop but the subsequent system call blocks until the original system call is finished (the main thread doesn't appear to block until this time, other activity does progress past the thread creation for the initial system call).  If I try the killall from a separate shell after my program invokes the prog, killlall works (as you'd expect).  I know that macOS has requirements on programs that interact with the ui libraries need to handle such activity from the main thread only.  Are there other requirements for programs shelling out to system(3) that I clearly am ignorant of?

On windows, the only difference in the code is the choices for "prog", and the behavior works as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

system() is expected to block until the launched program exits -- if it didn't, there would be no way for system() to return the exit-status of the child process  as part of its return value.

If you want your thread to continue executing in parallel with the child process, you will need to use a different API (typically fork() followed by calling exec() from the child-process's branch of the fork) instead.

Comment: I guess I don't understand enough about threading.  If one thread makes a call to system I would expect that call to block, if another thread makes a call to system... why would the second call block on the first from separate threads?  Are you saying that this is a property of system, and that the kernel doesn't... let you do this inside the context of a program regardless  of the use of threads?  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Only the thread that is calling system() should block inside the system() call.

Comment: Thats what I thought, which is why I mentioned that my initial approach was to spin up a thread for the first system call, and kill it from another.